# Определение структуры внутри union без имени, как маршалировать?

Tags: c#, com, struct

Я немного не понял как мне маршалировать такое объединение:

```
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

При том раскладе что `DUMMYSTRUCTNAME` не имеет значения, т.е. он пуст.

Правильно ли я сделал?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct LargeInteger
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DummyStruct
    {
        public uint LowPart { get; set; }
        public long HighPart { get; set; }
    }

    [FieldOffset(0)] public DummyStruct DummyStructField;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public DummyStruct u;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public long QuadPart;
}
```

Comment: На первый взгляд, правильно.

Comment: Очень смущает дублирование `DummyStruct`.

Comment: _дублирование DummyStruct_ - единственное, что приходит на ум, это сделано, чтобы писать короткое `u` вместо длинного `DUMMYSTRUCTNAME` (которое используется в другом месте по соглашению имен).

Comment: [Windows Data Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types). LONG - 32-bit. LONGLONG - 64 bit.